# How to use \citet and \citep with bibtex and the verbose-trad2 style?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, natbib, biber

I'm using biblatex with the verbose-trad2 style. I want to be able when I cite the author within the text, to have something like

```
   According to \citet{Gavard-Perret_2012}
```

Expected output:

> According to Gavard-Perret et al. (2012)

And :

```
blabla blabla (\citep{Gavard-Perret2012})
```

Expected output:

> As blabla blabla  (Gavard-Perret et al., 2012b)

A short exemple

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper, 12pt, french]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, top=3cm, headheight=26pt, headsep=25pt, heightrounded]{geometry}
\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false} %more common footnote style
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc} % footnote presentation
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} % level of sectioning titles printed in TOC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} %sectioning titles are numbered: level 5
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % nom du chapitre apparait en TOC
\graphicspath{{\images}}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs, hhline}
\usepackage[justification=centering, margin=2cm,font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{xltabular, siunitx, lscape}
\newcounter{tabenum}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{setspace} %interligne 1.5
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % espace entre deux paragraphes
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[explicit, clearempty]{titlesec}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{enumitem} % modifier et personaliser les puces des listes
\usepackage{pifont} % les symboles pour les listes
\usepackage[french]{minitoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,colorlinks=true,breaklinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\AtBeginEnvironment{footcitedquote}{\singlespacing\small}
\AtBeginEnvironment{fancyquotes}{\small}
\setlength{\overfullrule}{5pt} 

%==================BIBLIOGRAPHIE==========================

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,citestyle=verbose-trad2,bibstyle=authoryear,strict,citepages=omit,idemtracker=false,loccittracker=false,pagetracker=true,opcittracker=false,dashed=false,autopunct=true, ibidpage=true,maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=3, isbn=false,sorting=nyt]{biblatex} 

\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\small\rm}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
 url = {en ligne},
}
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\mkbiblege}[1]{%
\begingroup
\blx@blxinit
\blx@setsfcodes
<#1>
\endgroup}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\space\mkbiblege{\url{#1}}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
pages = {pp \adddot},
}

%to remove the In from the references
 \renewbibmacro{in:}{%
 \ifboolexpr{%
 test {\ifentrytype{article}}%
 or
 test {\ifentrytype{inproceedings}}%
 }{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}%
 }
 %\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}%last name first then first only 
  forending references
 \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} % for both
 \DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
 \renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{} % enlever la virgule après le nom
 \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\addspace} 

  %ibid, opcit....
 \renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
 \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
 \global\togglefalse{cbx:fullcite}%
 \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
 \bibhypertarget{cite\the\value{instcount}}{%
 \ifciteseen
  {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\iffirstonpage% NEW
       {\usebibmacro{cite:name}% NEW
        \usebibmacro{cite:title}}% NEW
       {\ifciteibid
          {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
          {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:name}}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
    % \usebibmacro{cite:save}}% DELETED
    \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}% NEW
     {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:full}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}}


%volume in biblio and citation
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{Vol. #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}%prefixes for 
  number journal

%newline url doi

 \newbibmacro*{bbx:parunit}{%
 \ifbibliography
 {\setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
 \usebibmacro{pageref}%
 \clearlist{pageref}%
 \setunit{\adddot\par\nobreak}}
{}}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
\usebibmacro{bbx:parunit}% Added
 \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
 {\printfield{doi}}
 {}%
 \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
 {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
 {}%
 \iftoggle{bbx:url}
 {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
  {}}

 \renewbibmacro*{eprint}{%
 \usebibmacro{bbx:parunit}% Added
 \iffieldundef{eprinttype}
  {\printfield{eprint}}
  {\printfield[eprint:\strfield{eprinttype}]{eprint}}}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
\usebibmacro{bbx:parunit}% Added
\printfield{url}%
\iffieldundef{urlyear}
 {}
{\setunit*{\addspace}%
 \printtext{\printurldate}}}

%commas as separators
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
\printfield{volume}%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
\printfield{number}%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
\printfield{eid}}
%\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
 \renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
 \usebibmacro{journal}%
 \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% was: \setunit*{\addspace}
 \iffieldundef{series}
  {}
  {\newunit
  \printfield{series}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}}% was: \setunit{\addspace}

 \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
 \setunit{\addspace}%
 \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
 \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
 \usebibmacro{issue}%
 \newunit}

 \AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{doi}} %supprimer doi des citations footnote
  \addbibresource{mabib.bib}

  \begin{document}

  \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Références bibliographiques}]
  \end{document}
```

and my `mabib.bib`

```
@book{Gavard-Perret_2012,
title = {Méthodologie de la recherche en sciences de gestion},
author = {Gavard-Perret, Marie-Laure and Gotteland, David and Haon, Christophe and Jolibert, Alain},
pagetotal = {415},
location = {France},
edition = {2\up{e} édition},
publisher = {Pearson},
date = {2012}
}
@book{Gavard-Perret2012,
title = {Réussir son mémoire ou sa thèse},
author = {Gavard-Perret, Marie-Laure and Gotteland, David and Haon, 
Christophe and Jolibert, Alain},
pagetotal = {300},
location = {France},
publisher = {Pearson},
date = {2012}
}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Your code doesn't declare any  bibresource!

Comment: Hello bernard. I gave an example of my .bib or are you talking about \addbibresource{mabib.bib}?Thank you

Comment: I meant the latter.

Comment: yes you're right I just add it to my code. Thank you :)

Comment: I've taken alook at your code, but the problem is that the citation style you chose (verbose-trad2) conflicts with what you want. I'll try to see if there's a workaround

Comment: @Bernard yes I know I use the verbose because It allows me to have the footnote citation (with op, cit , ibid, etc.) but sometimes I just need the author& year within the text without the citation footnote (the reference would be in the bibliography). ok thank you so much :).

Comment: Couldn't you as well use  `\footcite` with a standard authoryear style?

Comment: @Bernard Well Idon't think it gives the same results as verbose (ex: op.cit when the same refernce is used, etc.) or may be I'm wrong?

Comment: if this is the case, and \footcite with the standard authoryear style gives the same the results as verbose ( footnote citation) and will allows me to solve my problem with the author&year citation within the text, I'm willing to use it ;)